# Need the following script to output and send to email

Tags: powershell, sendmail, email

Will start with, I'm not very PS savvy.

I have found the following script in a comment on a tech site, it does everything I want it to, but was wondering if I could generate the output into the body of an email and send to whatever specified address. The script is below.

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"   
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()   
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()   
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,    
@{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){   
    1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},   
@{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){ 
    1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};
    4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}  
}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, but you will need to add the correct information in the Send-MailMessage command.

Here is the send-mailmessage technet with more information about the possible parameters and what not https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"

$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

$result = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,@{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){
   1 {"Installation"}; 
   2 {"Uninstallation"}; 
   3 {"Other"}}}},
   @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){ 
   1 {"In Progress"}; 
   2 {"Succeeded"}; 
   3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};
   4 {"Failed"}; 
   5 {"Aborted"}}}}

$html = "Dear Person, <br/>" 
$html += "Here are the windows update results <br/>"; 
$html += "<table>" 
$html += "<tr>"
$html += "<th>Date of Install</th>"
$html += "<th>Operation</th>"
$html += "<th>Status</th>" 
$html += "</tr>"

foreach ($line in $result) 
{ 
    $date = $line.Date.ToShortDateString()
    $op = $line.Operation
    $stat = $line.Status
    $html += "<tr>"
    $html += "<td> $date </td>" 
    $html += "<td> $op </td>"
    $html += "<td> $stat </td>"
    $html += "</tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.server" -Body $html -BodyAsHtml -From "UpdateSearcher@maildomain.com" -To "Recipient@maildomain.com" -Subject "subject"
```

Comment: I think I almost got something like this, but I get the same error message -
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:19 char:127

Comment: try changing the -Body $result  to -Body $Result.ToString()

Comment: nevermind that wont work. i made a new edit try that

Comment: Oh, it's worked, but it's given me an odd output. Is that a format issue?



@{Date=09/23/2016 04:37:28; Operation=Installation; Status=Succeeded} '
' @{Date=09/16/2016 05:57:49; Operation=Installation; Status=Succeeded} '
' @{Date=09/16/2016 05:57:34; Operation=Installation; Status=Succeeded} '

Comment: Added $html = $html.Replace("@{","").Replace("}","") before sending the command, u can see the edit, it should remove the brackets and the @'s then u have it semicolon seperated

Comment: You are a legend! I dropped a piece of the script, but was able to add it back in, was just Title on the end - 5 {"Aborted"}}}}, Title. I'm stoked with that, I feel bad for asking another question haha. Is there a way to put it into columns (purely cosmetic, so doesn't matter too much if not), with a title headings? For example, having Date of install as one column, Status of installation and then the Title of the update?

Comment: Thats perfect. I tried to add the "title" back in, but I can't seem to get it to function, does it have to be a variable or something. From your previous edit, I could add title after this line like so - 5 {"Aborted"}}}}, Title. That gave me the title of the update itself. I tried to do it by reading yours and adjusting, I was able to add the column for it, but the data doesn't populate.

Comment: I got it! I added $line.Title and it all worked. I'll start fiddling around to get alignment right and I should be good. I can't even upvote your answer -_-, it won't let me.

Comment: Got it, thanks for all your help. I ended up being able to add a couple simple lines, pulling the hostname, uptime and the number of pending updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to send mails directly via SMTP you can put your output into a variable and send it with `Send-MailMessage`

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$MailBody = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Date,

@{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){

   1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},

@{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){

   1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"};

   4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}

}}}


Send-MailMessage -From "Your Name <your@mail.com>" -To "Receiver1 <Receiver1@mail.com>", "Receiver2 <Receiver2@mail.com>" -Subject "Microsoft Update Session" -Body $MailBody -SmtpServer "your.smtpserver.com"
```

Comment: I also get the same message above with this, when I was trying to figure it out before posting I know I had seen it. Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:19 char:127